# Delete value from Firebase Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using OneSignal to send push notifications from cloud functions. The OneSignal response also sends me an array with `player ids` which didn't work. I would like to delete them from the database. Is there any way to delete them without knowing the `userKey`?

Database:

```
playerIds
    userKey
      player_id1: true,
      plaher_id2: true
```

Cloud function:

```
      let errors = response.errors.invalid_player_ids;

      let playerIdsRef = admin.database().ref('/playerIds/');

      for (let error of errors) {
        console.log(error)
        playerIdsRef.orderByChild(error).equalTo(true).on("value", function (snapshot) {
          console.log(snapshot);
          console.log(snapshot.val()); //this returns null
          snapshot.delete(); // this returns snapshot.delete is not a function

        });
      }
```

Comment: You want to be using once() instead of on() for a one-time query.

Comment: That's because there's no `delete()` function on DataSnapshot. What you should do is get the key to that snapshot and set the value to null to delete it: `playerIdsRef.child(snapshot.key).setValue(null);`

Comment: But before that, you might want to solve the problem of `snapshot.val()` returning null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved my problem:

```
    if (response.errors.invalid_player_ids.length > 0) {
      const errors = response.errors.invalid_player_ids;
      const playerIdsRef = admin.database().ref('/playerIds/');

      for (let error of errors) {
        playerIdsRef.orderByChild(error).equalTo(true).once("value", (snapshot) {
          const snapshotValue = snapshot.val();
          const key = Object.keys(snapshotValue)[0];
          //or
          //const key = Object.keys(snapshot.val())[0];
          playerIdsRef.child(key).child(error).set(null);
        });
      }
    }
```